# Написал функцию DrawLine в tkinter, но при её использовании появляется ошибка:

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, tkinter, button

Написал функцию `DrawLine` в *tkinter*, но при её использовании появляется ошибка:

> TypeError: DrawLine() missing 4 required positional arguments: x1, y1, x2, and y2

С чем она может быть связана?

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create an instance of Tkinter frame
win= Tk()

#Set the geometry of the window
win.geometry("700x250")

img=np.ones((1400,1400,3))
def DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx=abs(x2-x1)
    dy=abs(y2-y1)
    
    if x1<x2:
        xs=1
    else:
        xs=-1
        
    if y1<y2:
        ys=1
    else:
        ys=-1
        
    x=x1
    y=y1
    
    if dx>dy:
        p=2*y-dx
        
        while x!=x2:
            x=x+xs
            if p>0:
                y=y+ys
                p=p+2*dy-2*dx
                
            else:
                p=p+2*dy
                
            img[y,x]=0
            
      
    else:
       
        p=2*x-dy
        
        while y!=y2:
            y=y+ys
            if p>0:
                x=x+xs
                p=p+2*dx-2*dy
                
            else:
                p=p+2*dx
                
            img[y,x]=0
            
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(5,5)
    plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"]=80
    
    figure, axes = plt.subplots()
    cc = plt.Circle(( x , y,), 50 , alpha=0.1) 
    axes.set_aspect( 1 ) 
    axes.add_artist( cc ) 
    axes.add_patch(cc)


    plt.ylim(-400, 1000)
    plt.xlim(-400, 1000)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    def main():
        a = int(input("x1: "))
        b = int(input("y1: "))
        c = int(input("x2: "))
        d = int(input("y1: "))
        x1 = a
        y1 = b
        x2 = c
        x3 = d
        DrawLine(a,b,c,d)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
#Create a Button to plot the graph
button= ttk.Button(win, text= "Graph", command= DrawLine)
button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=lambda: DrawLine(тут пишите координаты линии)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


win= Tk()
win.geometry("700x250")

img = np.ones((1400, 1400, 3))

def drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = abs(x2 - x1)
    dy = abs(y2 - y1)
    
    if x1 < x2:
        xs = 1
    else:
        xs =- 1
        
    if y1 < y2:
        ys = 1
    else:
        ys =- 1
        
    x = x1
    y = y1
    
    if dx > dy:
        p = 2 * y - dx
        
        while x != x2:
            x = x + xs
            if p > 0:
                y = y + ys
                p = p + 2*dy - 2*dx
            else:
                p = p + 2*dy
            img[y, x]=0
    else:
        p = 2*x - dy
        while y != y2:
            y = y + ys
            if p > 0:
                x = x + xs
                p = p + 2*dx - 2*dy
            else:
                p = p + 2*dx
            img[y, x]=0
            
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (5, 5)
    plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 80
    
    figure, axes = plt.subplots()
    cc = plt.Circle((x, y,), 50, alpha=0.1) 
    axes.set_aspect(1) 
    axes.add_artist(cc) 
    axes.add_patch(cc)

    plt.ylim(-400, 1000)
    plt.xlim(-400, 1000)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    
def main():
    a = int(input("x1: "))
    b = int(input("y1: "))
    c = int(input("x2: "))
    d = int(input("y1: "))
    x1 = a
    y1 = b
    x2 = c
    x3 = d
    drawLine(a, b, c, d)
    
#    if __name__ == "__main__":
#        main()
        
#Create a Button to plot the graph
button= ttk.Button(win, text= "Graph", command=main)       #  - DrawLine
button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]